# Add a newline character in a string of the title of a colorbar

Tags: matlab

I want to newline character in a string. \n doesn't work.

Problem: I wish the title of a colorbar to be displayed in two lines.

Code:

```
h = colorbar;
set(get(h,'title'),'string','Total distance moved by staying individuals away from their initial position (m)');
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have multiple lines in a title, you have to pass a cell to the `title` function:

```
title({'Line 1', 'Line 2'});
```

For colorbar titles, it's the same idea:

```
set(get(h, 'Title'), 'String', {'Line 1', 'Line 2'})
```

and the result (with a random image):

[image]

Best,

Comment: Thanks! I came across your stated solution, but apparently it didn't work or probably I wrote it incorrectly. Can you provide complete code please? Sorry I am new to Matlab.

Comment: @AB: I've edited my answer to adapt it to your code.